# Matrix calculation and calculus in general form

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Can Mathematica do the followings? (Note that dimension of matrices are given by general parameters like $m,n$)

1. Can it do matrix calculation in general form? For example solving the following equation $XA=B$ where $A,B$ are matrix and $X$ is a vector. The solution is $X=A^{-1}B$. The goal is basically to derive some equations in general form. If it cannot do that, any form of **Collect** function can be useful. At least being able to collect the following expression with respect to $X$: $2X+AX$ (a formula like **Collect**$[2X+AX,X]$). The answer should be $(2+A)X$
2. Can Mathematica do matrix calculus as well? For example taking derivative with respect to $X$ for $X'AX$ for which the answer is $(A+A')X$

Note that I prefer a general form. One might for example define the matrix by $A=[a_{11},a_{12},...]$, but then the inverse would be a messy expression.

if these are not possible is there any other software which can do something like that?

Comment: I guess some of them can be implemented but others not. Please see this GUIDE page [Symbolic Tensors](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SymbolicTensors.html) and related Tutorials for more.

Comment: Might want to have a look at the NCAlgebra Mathematica package.

Comment: Thanks Αλέξανδρος-Ζεγγ and daniel-lichtblau. These are great suggestions. It seems that NCAlgebra is more tuned for Matrix Calculus. I should look more into that, for example how to convert a vector to a diagonal matrix, etc.